# Linux unexpected things with shell and cmake etc

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, cmake

I am facing a strange issue with cd command and cmake.

- cd command is not working with the paths which contain '-' minus sign in it. (unless used by tab expansion which is not desireable as path will be provided by ENV variable)
- cmake issue

`export $SOME_VAR=Some_value_for_this_variable`

Now using this in cmake as
`set (SOME_OTHER_VAR "$ENV{SOME_VAR}/SUFFIX")`

above should give the output as `SOME_OTHER_VAR=Some_value_for_this_variable/SUFFIX` but instead it is replacing the env variable from starting and giving the output as `SOME_OTHER_VAR=SUFFIXalue_for_this_variable` means Some_v is replaced from starting with SUFFIX which is not expected.

Please help as i am not getting whats happening.

Comment: Worse than that, the '/' is disappearing altogether! If the string started with "/SUFFIX" I would say you have a carriage return in your string...

Answer (score 0):

You're having some sort of character set issue.  There are two different minus signs.  The hyphen - (ASCII 45, U+002D), and the real minus sign − (U+2212).  It's possible that the filename itself got the non-ASCII minus sign, which you can't easily type with your keyboard.  The easiest fix would be to rename the file to the normal hyphen.  Otherwise, you have to convince CMake to understand your Unicode filename.  I have no idea if that's easy or hard.

I think your second problem is similar.  The environment variable likely one or more non-printing characters in it, messing up the CMake variables, or at least the display.  Try this: from the Linux command prompt, inspect the actual contents of the string.

```
echo $SOME_VAR | od -t c
```

For ASCII representation of everything, and/or

```
echo $SOME_VAR | od -t d1
```

for the byte contents